# rsync crashes machine while performing sync on glusterfs mounted share

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, glusterfs

I am running ubuntu 14.04 as guest inside virtualbox 5.0.3 on OS X. While performing rsync on a glusterfs (3.7.x) mounted share with over 100.000 files, the entire machine crashes.

There is one particular /var/log/syslog entry of interest:

```
    INFO: task rsync:4114 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340183]       Not tainted 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340381] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340513] rsync           D ffff8800d87e7e08     0  4114   4104 0x00000000
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340518]  ffff8800d87e7e08 ffff8800da169d70 0000000000013e80 ffff8800d87e7fd8
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340521]  0000000000013e80 ffff8800da31c4b0 ffff8800da169d70 ffff8800d87e7e18
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340523]  ffff8800db6555e0 ffff8800d9558800 ffff8800d87e7e30 ffff8800db6556b0
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340526] Call Trace:
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340534]  [<ffffffff817b22e9>] schedule+0x29/0x70
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340538]  [<ffffffff812dc06d>] __fuse_request_send+0x11d/0x290
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340542]  [<ffffffff810b4e10>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0x110/0x110
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340545]  [<ffffffff812dc1f2>] fuse_request_send+0x12/0x20
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340548]  [<ffffffff812e576d>] fuse_flush+0x12d/0x180
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340551]  [<ffffffff811e9973>] filp_close+0x33/0x80
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340554]  [<ffffffff8120a152>] __close_fd+0x82/0xa0
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340556]  [<ffffffff811e99e3>] SyS_close+0x23/0x50
    Aug 24 20:39:15 localhost kernel: [ 8974.340560]  [<ffffffff817b668d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

What could be the potential cause of this and how could I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Take a look at your GlusterFS logs (on the client and servers).  Log location varies (between distributions and how the software is installed).  They're most likely in `/var/log/glusterfs` or in `/usr/local/var/log/glusterfs`.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running out of memory?

Comment: @Gene which log do you mean of the many in the logfolder? I also just realized that there is a data-nfs.log logging thousands of entries while renaming files ".filenam.jpg" into "filename.jpg" - The VMs have 4GB of RAM each on a macbook with 16GB RAM.

Comment: Have you managed the issue? We've faced the similar one. [Here is](https://www.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-devel/2016-January/047791.html) our description in GlusterFS mailing list. Similarly, we are not running out of memory, and the logs are mostly empty. Renaming entries you've described seem to be normal situation — that is how rsync works.

Comment: Yes, eventually I solved it back in August - which is why I not entirely remember the fix. I believe it was related to memory. There was no problem in production. Worth to mention is also that I moved the gluster share to thinly provisioned LVM volumes which might have been part of the fix.

Comment: I had the same problem on macOS doing a local copy with no virtual machine involved. BOOM! and the machine restarted. I was stooped at writing this own message.